# How to add/remove dropdown multiselect list items in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a multiselect dropdown list and filled items from database like below, it works fine the first time, but based on selections from other dropdowns, I need to remove values and add other values.

```
$('#PID').multiselect({
    columns: 1,
    placeholder: 'Select project'
});
```

I am unable to modify the dropdown's values, can anybody help me?

I referred to the link below.

http://www.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/

I tried something like the following:

```
$("#PID").append('<option value="option5">Option ' + ++count + '</option>');
$("#PID").multiselect('refresh');
```

Comment: Can you try and elaborate more on what you mean by you are unable to "modify the dropdown's values?" What exactly is the action you are trying to perform, and how is it not working?

Answer (score 3):

Demo link http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/create-add-remove-select-lists-using-jquery/

```
<form>
  <fieldset>

    <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="4">Item 4</option>
    </select>

    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>

    <select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="5">
      <option value="5">Item 5</option>
      <option value="6">Item 6</option>
      <option value="7">Item 7</option>
    </select>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unload multiselect dropdown using below code and reinitialize it:

```
$('#PID').multiselect( 'unload' );
```

You can also reload using below code:

```
$('#PID').multiselect( 'reload' );
```

Please check [here](https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect) for more options.